Constructing a basis for a tensor product
Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces of a field $\mathbb{K}$. Let $\left\{v_i : i \in \mathcal{I}\right\}$ be a basis of $V$, and $\left\{w_j : j \in \mathcal{J}\right\}$ be a basis of $W$. Let $V \otimes W$ be a tensor product of $V$ and $W$ with a bilinear map $\otimes: V \times W \rightarrow V \otimes W$. I am trying to prove that $\left\{ v_i \otimes w_j : i \in \mathcal{I}, j \in \mathcal{J}\right\}$ is a basis of $V \otimes W$. I have already shown that the products $v_i \otimes w_j$ are linearly independent, but I fail to show that they span $V \otimes W$.
Let $U$ be the vector subspace of $V \otimes W$ spanned by the products $v_i \otimes w_j$. It follows from the universal property that $U$ is isomorphic to the tensor product $V \otimes W$. Let $\varphi: U \rightarrow V \otimes W$ be a bijective linear map. Then $\left\{ \varphi(v_i \otimes w_j) : i \in \mathcal{I}, j \in \mathcal{J} \right\}$ is a basis of $V \otimes W$. If $U$ is finite-dimensional, it follows easily that $U=V \otimes W$, but I am not sure how to cover the case if $U$ is infinite-dimensional.

The universal property tells you more; it tells you that the unique map which sends $v_i\otimes w_j$ to its copy in $U$ is an isomorphism. Does this answer your question?

@UriGeorgePeterzil Yes, I didn't notice that the bijective linear map is in fact the identity map.

If the pair $(V\otimes W,\otimes)$ is a tensor product of vector spaces $V$ and $W$ with tensor product map $\otimes:V\times W\to V\otimes W$, then the pair satisfies the universal property:

For any vector space $U$ and bilinear map $\varphi:V\times W\to U$, there is a unique linear map $f:V\otimes W\to U$ with $\varphi=f\circ\otimes$:
$$\varphi(v,w)=f(v\otimes w)\quad\text{for all }v\in V,w\in W\tag{1}$$

It follows from the uniqueness condition in this universal property that the image subset
$$\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}\otimes=\{\,v\otimes w\mid v\in V,w\in W\,\}\subseteq V\otimes W$$
must span $V\otimes W$. If it did not, then the map $f$ in the universal property would not be unique in general--there might be $g$ also satisfying (1) but disagreeing with $f$ on the stuff in $V\otimes W$ outside of the span of $\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}\otimes$.
More formally if we let $T$ denote the span of $\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}\otimes$, then $\otimes$ restricts to the bilinear map $\varphi:V\times W\to T$ given by $\varphi(v,w)=v\otimes w$. By the universal property with $U=T$, there is an induced linear map $f:V\otimes W\to T$ with $f(v\otimes w)=v\otimes w$. If $i:T\to V\otimes W$ denotes the inclusion map, then we have $if:V\otimes W\to V\otimes W$ satisfying $if(v\otimes w)=v\otimes w$. But the identity map on $V\otimes W$ also satisfies this property, so by the uniqueness condition of the universal property with $U=V\otimes W$, $if$ is the identity map and $i$ is surjective, that is $T=V\otimes W$.
Now if $\{v_i\mid i\in\mathcal{I}\}$ spans $V$ and $\{w_j\mid j\in\mathcal{J}\}$ spans $W$, then $\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}\otimes$ is contained in the span of the subset
$$\mathcal{S}=\{v_i\otimes w_j\mid i\in\mathcal{I},j\in\mathcal{J}\}$$
because for any $v\in V$ and $w\in W$ we can write $v=\sum_i\alpha_iv_i$ and $w=\sum_j\beta_jw_j$, and
$$v\otimes w=\sum_{i,j}\alpha_i\beta_j\,v_i\otimes w_j$$
It follows that $\mathcal{S}$ spans $V\otimes W$, since $\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}\otimes$ does.
